# Работа с формой с помощью jQuery

Tags: jquery, форма

помогите разобраться, мне нужно сделать следующее. Есть поле ввода

```
<textarea id="comment" cols="1"></textarea>
```

При нажатии на него, атрибуты поля меняются на `cols="3"`  и под полем появляется кнопка, а если щелкнуть на пустое место на странице, то поле опять становится однострочным и кнопка исчезает. Изменить атрибут и вывести кнопку при нажатии на поле ввода получилось, а вот сделать ее опять однострочной и убрать кнопку не получается, условие не срабатывает, в консоли в Chrome ошибок нет. http://pastebin.com/Wy9zwGaz Если вместо `$('body').mousedown` написать `$('table').mousedown`, то все работает так как нужно (на той же странице есть таблица, при нажатии на которую, условие срабатывает). Может кто поможет разобраться?

Comment: вы уверены? Вот практически ваш код почти без изменений, но проблему воспроизвести не удалось. Всё работает как вы и описали.

http://jsfiddle.net/jUJ3U/

Comment: Слушай, ну зачем так сурово-то? Существует событие onfocus жи

Comment: существует. Но мало ли, какие у товарища причины именно mousedown использовать

Comment: А если [использовать][1] `html` как селектор? Должно работать во всех условиях. Или это не очень корректно?


  [1]: http://jsfiddle.net/xaDWv/

Comment: uzumaxy, ты имеешь ввиду ('#html') ?

прописал вместо mousedown focus и blur, но кнопку то нажать не удается, фокус с поля пропадает и кнопка удаляется и не успевает нажаться. То есть можно ли как то написать проверку/условие, типа если нажата кнопка или другая область, то форма не закрывается, если нажата другая область, форма закрывается

Comment: Нет, не селектор с ID 'html', а именно селектор 'html'. Впрочем на [примере][1] все видно.
Уж лучше покажите Ваш код front-end полностью, а то чудеса творятся — у всех работает, кроме Вас.

  [1]: http://jsfiddle.net/xaDWv/

Comment: uzumaxy, вот страница на которой форма http://pastebin.com/MgGt5Pjf
вот код jquery http://pastebin.com/pwf0JYDd У меня при нажатии на форму она открывается, но при повторном нажатии на нее она закрывается. А должно быть, что бы при нажатии на любую область на странице кроме самой формы и например кнопки она закрывалась Прописал ('html:not(#comment)'), но это не работает

Comment: вы на jsfiddle рабочий пример покажите.

Comment: Согласно [этому][1] коду у Вас будет создано столько <html> тегов, сколько итераций в цикле `<?php foreach ($data as $value):?>`, причем эти все <html> теги со своим содержимым будут располагаться на одной веб-странице. Естественно, в таких условиях JS будет работать неправильно.

Откройте в браузере исходный код страницы и посмотрите на результат работы скрипта...


  [1]: http://pastebin.com/MgGt5Pjf

Comment: Елена, http://jsfiddle.net/BqEMp/ если кликнуть по форме, она откроется, если еще раз кликнуть по ней, она закроется, а такого быть не должно, и при клике на кнопке, форма тоже не должна закрываться.
uzumaxy, в исходном коде один открывающий тег html и один закрывающий. Я код давно посмотрел уже. Я сейчас все это на чистой html странице сделал, в ней каркас html страницы, не каких циклов и тоже самое, только в консоли при нажатии на форму написано event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead. А в той странице с циклами, ошибок нет не каких в консоли

Answer (score 1):

[@sew810i9](/users/12632/sew810i9), вот ваш код: http://jsfiddle.net/BqEMp/1/ . Он только самую малость изменён, в основном мегаскрипт сокращён до одной строчки. Всё работает так, как вы и описывали.

Comment: Елена, при нажатии на пустое место форма не закрывается и кнопка не исчезает! Или вы это не делали? Это должны быть уже другая функция для скрытия кнопки и формы?

Comment: так вы такое имели в виду?  http://jsfiddle.net/BqEMp/3/

Comment: почти, при нажатии на кнопку, форма не должна закрываться. Извините за назойливость.

Comment: значит, просто так и надо сделать: http://jsfiddle.net/BqEMp/4/

Comment: Елена, большое спасибо. Мне просто надо было добавить к моему коду
$('.so-hard').click(function(e){
 e.stopPropagation();
    });
то есть запретить использование функции при нажатии на соответствующий контейнер. И возможно все сработало бы)

Comment: вероятно так. stopPropagation действительно останавливает распространение события